# Walmart Orders API: No matter what limit I set I always get back 40 results

Tags: walmart-api

I successfully managed to authenticate and get results from the api using the following API endpoint and params (orders created after 2019-01-01 with a limit of 200 results per page)

https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/orders?createdStartDate=2019-01-01&limit=200&shipNodeType=SellerFulfilled

Here is the API documentation: https://developer.walmart.com/#/apicenter/marketPlace/latest#getAllOrders

The results meta data indicated a total of 303 orders, with a page size (limit) of 200, however only 40 results were listed (and not ).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<ns3:list xmlns:ns2="http://walmart.com/mp/orders" xmlns:ns3="http://walmart.com/mp/v3/orders" xmlns:ns4="com.walmart.services.common.model.money" xmlns:ns5="com.walmart.services.common.model.name" xmlns:ns6="com.walmart.services.common.model.address" xmlns:ns7="com.walmart.services.common.model.address.validation" xmlns:ns8="http://walmart.com/"> 
 <ns3:meta> 
 <ns3:totalCount>303</ns3:totalCount> 
 <ns3:limit>200</ns3:limit> 
 </ns3:meta> 
 <ns3:elements> 
 <ns3:order>
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong, and what I can do to get the rest of the results.

Comment: This looks 100% correct at first glance.  I'm not seeing a nextCursor in the response.  Was there one, or did you edit it out?  I know I've been having odd results from this call within the past couple of weeks.  I'll take a closer look when I have access to my notes and code.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't duplicate your error.  Using the exact same endpoint, I got the full 200 orders, and a nextCursor that worked for the remainder.  There have been changes to the Order API in the past week, so maybe it was a temporary glitch on their end. Try again?   Was the response truncated after 40 orders, or did the XML response include the final </ns3:elements></ns3:list> tags and only 40 <ns3:order> elements?

Comment: do you follow any guide for authenticate and get token .